# ¿Como puedo sumar 5 números introducidos pero descartando números negativos y el número 0?

Tags: javascript

cuando introduzca el número `0` o cualquier negativo que no lo tome en cuenta, esto llevo del código

```js
var num;
var suma = 0;
var i = 1;
alert("Programa que perimte calcular la suma de 5 numeros");

while (i<=5) {
 num = prompt("Ingrese 5 numeros");    
 suma = parseInt(suma) + parseInt(num);
 i++;  
}
document.write("la suma de los 5 numeros es: " +suma);
```

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a él método [`Math.sign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) Puedes averiguar el signo del número introducido y solo en caso de ser positivo, tomarlo en cuenta para su suma:

```js
var num;
var suma = 0;
var i = 1;
alert("Programa que perimte calcular la suma de 5 numeros");

while (i <= 5) {
 num = prompt("Ingrese 5 numeros");
 
 if( Math.sign(parseInt(num)) === 1 ) {
   suma = parseInt(suma) + parseInt(num);
 }
 
 i++;  
}
document.write("la suma de los 5 numeros es: " + suma);
```

Comment: el  ++i  debe ir para hacer lo pedido dentro del if

Comment: lo comprobé  con el acumulador dentro del if  {... ... ++i} no cuenta ni suma los valores negativos ni al 0   tampoco entra en ningún ciclo infinito hace lo que se pide https://js.do/

Comment: con el acumulador fuera del if  luego de ingresar 5 enteros para y se pide que se ingresen 5 valores que no sean 0 ni tampoco negativos

Comment: if(... ) {
   suma = parseInt(suma) + parseInt(num);
    i++; 
 }
 es lo que se pide ingresar 5 números que no sean 0 ni negativos  que cumplan la condición  si ejecuto tu código e ingreso 5 números negativos para y no permite ingresar el tipo de números pedidos  ejecutalo https://js.do/

Answer (score -1):

> hay muchas formas de resolverlo una es usando un condicional if
> estudia como usarlo adecuadamente
>
> > De acuerdo a tu codigo --> este codigo hace lo pedido

[podes ejecutarlo en este link](https://js.do/)

```
    var num;
        var suma=0;
        var i=1;
        alert("Programa que perimte calcular la suma de 5 numeros");
        
        while (i<=5) {
        
        num=prompt("Ingrese 5 numeros");  
        if(num >0){
        suma=parseInt(suma)+ parseInt(num);
        i++;
/*
     con el acumulador dentro del if  te permite ingresar 
     5 números y así  no contabilizar cuando se ingrese al 0 o números negativos */
        }
        }
```

Comment: Hacerle los deberes a la gente no está muy bien visto por estos lares. Copiar y pegar no le va a enseñar absolutamente nada. El primer paso antes de preguntar siempre es **intentarlo**.

Comment: si no sabe como y cuando usar un  if no veo lo malo en decirle